# Built login system with laravel

Tags: laravel

Please I want to be able to display logged username on navigation bar after login. Please I need help. The default way like it was  I saw in the built in login system that shipped with laravel is

Auth::user()->name

I am using a different model this time.

My model name is Student.

Please how do I go about it

Comment: You can user helper `auth()->user()->name`

Comment: @Espresso That's just a different syntax for the same thing. OP needs something different.

Comment: I am not using the built in auth system.

Comment: I built mine myself.

Comment: Do you have some relation between `User` and `Student`?

Comment: If you have multiple guards you will have to specify which guard used to authenticate that user like this `auth('guardName')->user()->name;`. for your case it will be `auth('student')->user()->name;`

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter what your model is. As long as it is defined as user provider model in auth.php, you can always access your user details with `Auth::user()` helper in Laravel

Comment: Thanks sir. I understand that. But this is not a normal user( so to speak) I have a student login system and I want to display the student name on login.